# How to add the 2nd item?

Tags: python

So, I got a list:

`list2= [['A', '0'], ['B', '1'], ['B', '4'], ['B', '2'], ['B', '0'], ['C', '0'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['D', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['D', '0']]`

**I need to add the second item if the first item in the sublist is the same**. How to do it?

```
result expected:[['A', 0],['B',7],['C',3],['D',5]]
```

Comment: How does adding an item result in a shorter list?

Comment: Simply loop over list and create a dictionary using the default key value if key doesn't exist or rather is added for the first time...

Comment: its not adding an item. lets just assume every second item in every sublist is a score and the letter ('A','B','C','D') is a person.. the result should be a sublist of each person with the total score. so for example: we got ['B', 7] from ['B', 1+4+2+0]

Comment: You could use a `collections.Counter` (although it will discard the `0` values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list2= [['A', '0'], ['B', '1'], ['B', '4'], ['B', '2'], ['B', '0'], ['C', '0'],
        ['C', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['D', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['D', '0']]
dict2 = {}
for a, b in list2:
    if dict2.get(a) is None:
        dict2[a] = int(b)
    else:
        dict2[a] += int(b)
rv = [[a, b] for a, b in dict2.items() ]
print(rv)
```

Using a dict to store count of first item of list

Answer (score 0):

Using collection:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

list2= [['A', '0'], ['B', '1'], ['B', '4'], ['B', '2'], ['B', '0'], ['C', '0'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['D', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['D', '0']]

result = defaultdict(int)
for item in list2:
    a, value = item
    result[(a)] += int(value)
print(sorted([[a, total] for a,total in result.items()], key=itemgetter(0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let,

```
>>> list2
[['A', '0'], ['B', '1'], ['B', '4'], ['B', '2'], ['B', '0'], ['C', '0'], ['C', '1'], ['C', '2'], ['D', '2'], ['D', '3'], ['D', '0']]
```

be the input

You can use itemgetter from operator module to get all the characters, and set() would get the unique elements.

With that in hand, you can iterate through the list2 to match every unique character and sum the resulting list!

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [(c,sum([int(val) for st,val in list2 if st==c])) for c in set(map(itemgetter(0),list2))]
[('A', 0), ('C', 3), ('B', 7), ('D', 5)]
```

Breaking down the code,

```
>>> map(itemgetter(0),list2)
['A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D']
>>> set(map(itemgetter(0),list2))
set(['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'])
>>> [(c,sum([int(val) for st,val in list2 if st==c])) for c in set(map(itemgetter(0),list2))]
[('A', 0), ('C', 3), ('B', 7), ('D', 5)]
```